# How to disable joystick control of grabbed object in XRRayInteractor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openxr

In the project I have added Player Movement with Joystick for both Right Controller and Left Controller.
There are objects for which XRGrabIntractable Script attached so that they are Grabbable when Ray is Pointed and Triggered.

when I use Trigger button and Pick up one of the object it is Grabbed.
But when I use the Joystick to move the player Grabbed Object in Hand also moves and Rotates.

Is it possible to disable the movement of the Grabbed Object when we use Joystick for player movement?

Unity Version: 2021.3.1f
Device: Pico Nio 3
XR Interaction Toolkit Version: 2.2.0

Checking to see if there is any default setup to disable movement of Grabbed Object with joystick.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to uncheck the Anchor control checkbox. See picture below.

[image: XRRayInteractor configuration]